# Cannot start Jupyter Notebook kernel in VSCode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

I tried to install the Jupyter Notebook Kernel on VSCode, and it cant seem to connect, it shows this text in the VSCode:

```
Failed to start the Kernel. 
C:\Users\Theodore\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\traitlets\traitlets.py:2412: FutureWarning: Supporting extra quotes around strings is deprecated in traitlets 5.0. You can use 'hmac-sha256' instead of '"hmac-sha256"' if you require traitlets >=5.
  warn(
C:\Users\Theodore\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\traitlets\traitlets.py:2366: FutureWarning: Supporting extra quotes around Bytes is deprecated in traitlets 5.0. Use '7d0f2f44-841e-4868-9c82-374720d9f73e' instead of 'b"7d0f2f44-841e-4868-9c82-374720d9f73e"'.
  warn(
Bad address (C:\projects\libzmq\src\epoll.cpp:100). 
View Jupyter log for further details.
```

Python version : 3.10.4
Jupyter Notebook Version: 6.4.12

I tried switching to the kernel from Anaconda, but it also doesn't seem to work. Sometimes it just asks me to reinstall the ipykernel again. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I have a VPN, and it made it crash, i used this in the CMD:

```
netsh winsock reset
```

and it worked. Thanks for your help

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Use command `pip install ipykernel` in the cmd.

**Alternative method:**

Use following command in the terminal to reinstall pyzmq package.

```
pip uninstall pyzmq
pip install pyzmq
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer, but it still won't work, this is what it shows now: 
```
Failed to start the Kernel. 
Bad address (C:\projects\libzmq\src\epoll.cpp:100). 
View Jupyter log for further details.
```